# How can I disable or remove "recent boards" from Trello?

Tags: trello

I use the top left board dropdown menu to quickly access boards. Unfortunately the "Recent Boards" portion of the menu is annoying - I don't like to see boards that I visited in a one-off manner, nor do I want to see my own recent boards. I also don't see an upper limit on this part of the menu, which keeps growing and taking up vertical screen space for board listings.

Is there a way to remove boards from the recent list or to disable that part of the board menu completely? Ideally I'd like to just see my starred boards, then personal boards, and then on with organization boards

Answer (score 1):

The Trello team recently introduced this feature and are likely fine-tuning it based on feedback.  A number of people have already provided similar feedback on the Trello development board.  Since it is not currently possible to "turn off" this feature, I recommend providing reinforcing feedback via this card:

[Recently Viewed Boards in Boards Page and Boards Header Menu](https://trello.com/c/Dl2G5TWE/1392-recently-viewed-boards-in-boards-page-and-boards-header-menu)

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something like this too in case anyone is interested, there is an extension that does exactly this!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-trello/bbfepffamdjkhfknckjcpjiedmacbjka